How to set custom JWT Authentication in django using dj-rest-auth
I have setup a backend JWT authentication system using django, dj-rest-auth and simpleJWT. I want a custom JWT token returned from the server to be used as the Bearer token.
Currently, the dj-rest-auth is using JWTCookieAuthentication by setting default jwt in the cookies. In this method, the Authorization header is of no use.
Another method which enables Authorization header is to use TokenAuthentication but I can't have custom JWTs as tokens.
I can use the simpleJWT package to create my custom tokens using /api/token but then it won't be useful for social authentication for which I have to use dj-rest-auth.
Is there a way to only enforce Authorization: Bearer "custom_JWT" authentication(not Token or Session or Cookie) and the token can be the custom JWT which I can set?
I have been searching for a solution for some days now but no luck.
My urls py file

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include(router.urls)),
        path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
        path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
        path('users/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
        path('users/registration/', CustomRegisterView.as_view(), name='custom_rest_register'),
    ]


serializer file

    class EnrichedTokenPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
        @classmethod
        def get_token(cls, user):
            token = super().get_token(user)
            // custom token logic
            return token


settings.py

    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [ 
            'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
            'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
            'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
        ],
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        ],
        'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    }
    
    SIMPLE_JWT = {
        "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "api.serializers.EnrichedTokenPairSerializer",
        'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    }
    
    REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
        'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'api.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer',
    }
    
    REST_AUTH = {
        'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'api.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer',
        'USE_JWT': True,
        'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'my-auth',
        'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE': 'my-token',
    }


I am using
Django>=5.0.2, django-allauth>=0.61.1, djangorestframework>=3.14.0, djangorestframework-simplejwt>=5.2.2, dj-rest-auth>=5.0.2
Any suggestions would be helpful.
